# Is there have any methods/techniques to improve the matrix multiplication speed in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently working on an project aim at finding blur region by using walsh hadamard transform. The basic idea is pixel-wise extract local patch and apply walsh hadamard transform to this local patch. In order to do Walsh hadamard transform, I prior generate the hadamard matrix H and do H×T(local_patch)×H_transpose computation. This operation cost 5ms per pixel which is time consuming. I'm wondering is there have some technique to speed up the matrix multiplication process in numpy python or using some other fast walsh hadamard trainsform technique to replace the H×T×H'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    for i in range(h):
      for j in range(w):
        local_patch_gray = gray_pad[i:i+patch_size, j:j+patch_size]
        local_patch_gray = local_patch_gray[1:, 1:]  # extract 2^n×2^n part
        local_patch_blur = blur_pad[i:i + patch_size, j:j + patch_size]
        local_patch_blur = local_patch_blur[1:, 1:]
        patch_WHT = np.dot(np.dot(H, local_patch_gray), H)
        blur_WHT = np.dot(np.dot(H, local_patch_blur), H)
        num = np.power(np.sum(np.power(np.abs(blur_WHT), p)), 1/p)
        denomi = np.power(np.sum(np.power(np.abs(patch_WHT), p)), 1/p)
        if denomi == 0:
            blur_map[i, j] = 0
            continue
        blur_map[i, j] = num / denomi
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? Asking because of range/xrange. I have a few other ideas too, putting those together now. Give a few.

Comment: python 3 language

Comment: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/wht/node2.html, I've found the content in this link is helpful, but local patch is a 2D array, in order to do the same operation in this link, am I suppose to flatten the 2D array into 1D vector? and apply the same trick proposed in this link?

Comment: What's the size of the arrays in the `dot` expressions? The normal numpy way of doing things faster is to avoid the i,j loops altogether.  Many iterations on something simple still takes a lot of time.

Comment: @DanielMing At a quick glance, you appear to be right. However, you will likely find the data manipulation for calculation will not outweigh the speed-up solutions I've proposed in my answer. However, don't hesitate to comment back if you need to bounce around ideas! I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: @hpaulj The local_patch size is 9×9, and I extract lower right 8×8 area by using local_patch_gray = local_patch_gray[1:, 1:]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a job for Numba, check out their [5-minute starting guide](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html).

In short, Numba compiles the first call of a function into a fast-callable format, so that every subsequent call of the same function is at light speed. Numba also has options which can make function calls at [ludicrous speed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAWL8ejf2nM). The options that will pertain to your example are likely `fastmath` and `parallel`.

As a starting point, here's what your new numba function might look like:

```py
@njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def lightning_fast_numba_function:
    local_patch_gray = gray_pad[i:i+patch_size, j:j+patch_size]
    local_patch_gray = local_patch_gray[1:, 1:]  # extract 2^n×2^n part
    local_patch_blur = blur_pad[i:i + patch_size, j:j + patch_size]
    local_patch_blur = local_patch_blur[1:, 1:]
    patch_WHT = np.dot(np.dot(H, local_patch_gray), H)
    blur_WHT = np.dot(np.dot(H, local_patch_blur), H)
    num = np.power(np.sum(np.power(np.abs(blur_WHT), p)), 1/p)
    denomi = np.power(np.sum(np.power(np.abs(patch_WHT), p)), 1/p)
    if denomi == 0:
        blur_map[i, j] = 0
        continue
    blur_map[i, j] = num / denomi

for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
        lighting_fast_numba_function()
```

Other options you may consider are using `np.nditer` instead of `range`. But, dont hesitate to cross-check options using Numpy's [iteration docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html).

Lastly, I noticed a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform) for your alg has a fast section, with Python code. Might find it useful.

Comment: `np.nditer` does not improve speed!  It doesn't 'compile' the body of the loop.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. wasn't trying to say "use nditer". Was more saying, these options might help you out as well, even if marginal.

Comment: I've used jit(nopython=True) in the previous code, and replace it with @njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True) seems won't increase too much real-time performance

Comment: And I just tried the python example code in the wikipedia. It aim at apply FWHTw on 1D array, so I flatten the local_patch to 1D array but an index error pump out.